# Por que (0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3 é diferente de 0.1 + (0.2 + 0.3)?

Tags: javascript

Em JavaScript `(0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3` resulta em `0.6000000000000001`. Já, `0.1 + (0.2 + 0.3)` resulta em `0.6`.

Por quê?

No snippet, é possível ver que essa "inconsistência" não acontece quando somo outros valores.

```js
console.log((0.1 + 0.2) + 0.3);
console.log(0.1 + (0.2 + 0.3));

console.log('-----');

console.log((0.4 + 0.5) + 0.6);
console.log(0.4 + (0.5 + 0.6));
```

Comment: Oi jbueno! Acho que esta pergunta é duplicada dessa outra. Se não concordares diz. Basicamente há um problema no cálculo visto que `0.1 + 0.2` dá `0.30000000000000004` e  `0.2 + 0.3` dá `0.5`

Comment: show da zueira contra  Javascript hoje :D

Comment: É duplicada sim, @Sergio. Eu não soube usar as palavras corretas para procurar. Só não entendo o motivo dos negativos =D

Comment: Òtimo! O voto negativo talvez seja porque é um problema +/- comum. Se não for esse o motivo não nei o que será.

Comment: Hehehe, sim. Acontece. Agora que eu notei que foi apenas um negativo, eu havia me engandado.

Comment: Agora entendi por quê aquela questão teve revisitações hoje... =D

Comment: Seja como for, a causa fundamental nesse caso é um pouco diferente. Não é a representação que está a enganar, mas sim a operação `+` que introduz o erro em `0.1 + 0.2` resultando em `0.30000000000000004` e logo depois ao somar `0.3` o erro não só é propagado, como também é ampliado, mais uma vez culpa do operador `+`.

Comment: Ao alterar a ordem das operações esse erro não é introduzido. Quando se faz `0.2 + 0.3` que dá exatamente `0.5` e logo depois ao somar `0.1` a representação se torna exatamente a de `0.6`... o que não é sorte nenhuma, haja visto que `0.5` é um número binário redondo.

Comment: Para ver como os números são representados de forma binária use este site: [IEEE-754 Analysis](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/)... é um pouco trabalhoso pegar a representação binária e operar bit a bit pra ver o que tá acontecendo, mas já ajuda muito.