# Erro aritmético Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hoje passei por um problema estranho, um calculo simples de soma da diferença de acordo com a ordenação.

Caso no console do navegador executar este calculo abaixo:

```
2.3+2.3+2.1
```

O valor esperado seria 6.7 correto? Pois é, mas da 6.699999999999999, até ai tudo bem, é entendível....

Mas.. se eu modificar a ordem dos valores, colocando o menor primeiro.

```
2.1+2.3+2.3
```

Surprise "mothafoca"! 6.7

Obs: Não posso usar toFixed pois não quero arrendodamento neste numero, onde pode me corrigir um problema agora, mas me resultar em algo pior la na frente.

Uma solução porquíssima que se passou na minha cabeça mas me nego a usar seria.

```
soma = 0;
[2.3, 2.3, 2.1].sort().forEach( valor => {
   soma += valor
});
```

Comment: [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/91)

Comment: Acredito que o problema mais estranho é a ordem dos valores.

Comment: [Por que 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 é diferente de 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154189/91)

Comment: Uma solução que eu encontrei seria utilizar .toPrecision(14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aritmética de números fracionários nunca é exata (pelo menos para números não múltiplos de potências de 1/2). A solução exata foi pura coincidência.

Uma forma de resolver a questão é converter o problema numa aritmética de inteiros (ou ponto fixo, não disponível em Javascript).

Assim, assumindo que se utiliza sempre uma casa decimal, a soma ficaria:

```
   23+21+23 = 67 // Exato!
```

Ainda assim, ao mostrar o resultado, 67/10 poderia resultar em algo do género 6.7000001 ou 6,999999...

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes com outros calculos já existentes, mas até o momento trabalahar com base 10 é o mais aceitável.

Comment: Como assim a aritmética de números fracionários nunca é exata? Está falando disso por causa da maneira que o JS implementa os números ou está falando somente no contexto matemático? 67 / 10 é 6.7 na matemática (considerando os axiomas padrões que usamos), ponto final, não tem isso de "poderia resultar em algo do género".

Comment: Apesar que matematicamente é possível provar que 6.7 é IGUAL a 6.69999... (dizima periodica infinita), usando: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: O problema é que informaticamente 6.999999 é diferente de 6.999..., isto é, não é infinito. Os números fracionários são normalmente aproximando (como em JavaScript) por somas de potências de 1/2 https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 . Com as operações aritméticas, os erros propagam-se.