# Porque (0.0015 * 3) == 0.0045 não retorna true?

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Porque a comparação `(0.0015 * 3) == 0.0045` no javascript não retorna true?

Ex.:

```js
var valor1 = 0.0015 * 3;
var valor2 = 0.0045;

if(valor1 == valor2) {
    console.log('Igual');
} else {
    console.log('Diferente');
}
```

Comment: Também pode ver mais detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101

Comment: Porque **`0.0015 * 3`** resulta em **`0.0045000000000000005`**

Comment: @bigown tem mais essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154189/18246

Comment: se fizer até a 17ª casa decimal vai dar IGUAL    if( valor1.toFixed(17) == valor2.toFixed(17) ) {    veja https://repl.it/KOZh/0

Comment: Pelo mesmo motivo que **0.1 + 0.1** não é **0.2**, veja o vídeo do canal Infinite Series (em inglês): https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8